# How to Customize Map Output Java

Tags: dictionary, customization, output

is it possible to customize Map output. I am using Ibatis as ORM, in the Sql query I am using the below query.

select employeeID, employeeName from employee where employeeID=101;

For some reason I need my map to be as "Expected".

Current Scenario :- populateMap {employeeID=101,employeeName=ram}

Expected :- populateMap {101,ram}

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about changing the output from the toString() of Map. is that right? In your context, can you sub-class map and use a sub-class?

Comment: No, I know once I append the toString method on my map it would become String. However I am looking my map should be as {101,ram}, instead of  {employeeID=101,employeeName=ram}. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say your map should be "{101,ram}", but I don;t know what that means. The map is going to be a map. The "{101,ram}" is a string output from some operation being performed on the map. What operation?  I'm still not clear on what you're asking. It would help if you create an extremely simple Java example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks Darius, I resolved my issue as earlier in the code I was using  :-                                                 Map<Integer,String> map=new Hashmap<Integer,String>();          which was returning map object from DB search results. However now I am assigning                                                    List<Employee> to the DB search results output, iterating the list and getting the value of employee ID as 101 and employeeName as Ram. Thanks a lot for your help.